# WP Sidebar Widget not showing correct text

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, sidebar

I'm working on my next Wordpress website for a customer (it's still on localhost so I can't give you a link). I got 4 pages and I need 2 sidebars. So I paste a code into `functions.php` for creating 2 sidebars:

```
<?php
    if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) 
        {
            register_sidebar(array('name' => 'Angebot'));
            register_sidebar(array('name' => 'Anfahrt'));
        }
?>
```

In the backend, the 2 sidebars are shown correctly and I can put some text into (I just put some random text for test in the sidebars and nothing else). And then I put some code into `index.php` and into `page.php`:

```
<div id="sidebar">        <?php if(is_page('Willkommen') || is_page('Angebot'))
            {
                get_sidebar('Angebot');
            }

            else
            {
                echo "Huhu";
            }
        ?>
    </div><!-- sidebar -->
```

I put the text "Huhu" in the else that I can see if the code works. And it does.

But my problem now is: It takes the sidebar I told it in my code but it doesn't show my text I put into the widget sidebar. It just show the `archive`, `categories`, `pages` etc. And I still don't know why.

Has someone an idea or can someone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this:-

```
get_sidebar('Angebot');
```

with this:-

```
dynamic_sidebar('Angebot');
```

Comment: You are boss! Thank you very much mate :) Works fine!